# Components in Grid with fixed size

Tags: java, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want to display a lot of component in a grid view, like the normal explorer in windows or other operating systems.
Is it possible to obtain this with a default or 3rd Party layout manager?

I tried Gridlayout and Springlayout (according to [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html#grid)).
Both resize the components relative to the parent dimension but I want **fixed** cell size and relative row and column numbers.
[image: Layoutmanager should handle this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both resize the components relative to the parent dimension

Create a panel using a GridLayout and add your components to this panel. Then add this panel to the `NORTH` of you frame instead of the `CENTER`. The NORTH will respect the size of the panel and all its components, wherease the `CENTER` will resize the panel based on the space available. Of course when you add the component to the NORTH it will never resize so you will not see scrollbars if they are needed.

Maybe other options would be to use:

1. A JList with a horizontal wrap. See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
2. The [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

these options allow the components to flow to a new row when necessary.

Comment: Thank you, Wrap Layout did it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).